# How to return a string that contains only characters that can form a valid int or float number?

Tags: python, regex, string

This problem wants me to remove non-numeric values from a passed string.

The question also says, "Remember that a numeric value can have a leading '+' or '-' and a float can have a decimal point (but only one decimal point)."

I didn't know that ints could have a leading + or -. How can I make a function that allows +'s and -'s but only before numerics, and decimals but only in the middle of numerics and not elsewhere?

I've looked around on StackOverflow and a lot of solutions for similar problems use regex which I'm not familiar with. Is there a way to do this with loops?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over your string a couple of times instead of doing regex. Once to filter out non-numeric characters, then once again to validate that that the remainder of a string is a number, with special checks to ensure that `+` or `-` is the first character and that only one decimal exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = r"^[+|-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$"

test_str = ("t1est\n"
    "23\n"
    "foo\n"
    "bar123\n"
    "304958\n"
    "bar\n"
    "+123\n"
    "-123.1\n"
    "-4\n"
    "4.5\n"
    "1.2.3\n"
    "2+3\n\n"
    "4\n"
    ".8\n"
    "-.8\n"
    "3.1415\n"
    "4,5")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```